# Why doesn't `ssh -t hostname_B.local -- zsh --interactive -c echo "this works"` work?

Tags: bash, ssh, zsh, tty

Why doesn't this work?:

```
hostname_A ~ % ssh -t hostname_B.local -- zsh --interactive -c echo "this works" 

Connection to hostname_B.local closed.
hostname_A ~ %
```

Blarrrrrrfrustration.

Answer (score 1):

Because it should be:

```
ssh -t hostname_B.local -- "zsh --interactive -c 'echo this works'"
```

Which does work, like-a so:

```
hostname_A ~ % ssh -t hostname_B.local -- "zsh --interactive -c 'echo this works'"
this works
Connection to hostname_B.local closed.
hostname_A ~ %
```

Yay!

(Good luck dealing with the insanity of string escapes in bash-like syntax, though. xD )